# InAppBrowser vs Web view vs System Web Browser

Tags: cordova

I'm working on a Cordova app at the moment, and none of the documentation is very clear about what the difference is between these three methods for displaying websites.

This is about the extent of the documentation, anywhere:

```
_self - opens in the Cordova WebView if url is in the white-list, else it opens in the InAppBrowser 
_blank - always open in the InAppBrowser 
_system - always open in the system web browser
```

Also, it doesn't state where I have to white-list URLs. Any suggestions there?

[Phonegap Docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html)

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32227524/82609

Answer (score 5, accepted):

_system option will switch and open in the phone's default browser.

_blank option will slide open an new window with browser controls from within the app and opens in it, you can close it to go back the previous view.

_self option will open in the app window and cannot go back to previous view.

---

whitelisting should be done in config.xml, here is documentation for white listing: [Cordova white-listing](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide)